# How do I read from a local file and write to Heroku remote (rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, heroku

I have an app that's working locally. I deployed it to heroku but the DB is completely empty.

I have an excel spreadsheet. Just FYI using excel as storage wasn't my idea. I also have a rake task that reads columns from the excel and writes to my DB.

```rb
require './lib/excel_util'
namespace :import do
  desc 'Import data from spreadsheet'

  task data: :environment do
    data =
      Roo::Spreadsheet.open(
        'lib/assets/sheet.xlsx'
      )
    headers = data.row(1) # index starts at 1 JFC
    data.each_with_index do |row, idx|
      next if idx == 0 # skip header  # create hash from headers and cells
      user_data = preprocess(data) # from my util library. mostly basic string operations
      user = User.new(user_data)
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Locally, I ran `bundle exec rails import:data` to populate the `users` db with excel entries. Everything works locally.

Now, I've tried to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` and `heroku rake import:data`. The second one doesn't work because I do not commit the excel file to my git repo.

How do I read from my excel locally and write DB entries to Heroku? The excel has about 100 entries. the approaches i can think of are

1. somehow scp this file to heroku and execute the same rake task on Heroku
2. find a way to execute rake task locally, but write to the remote DB on heroku
3. store the file in another remote location, like S3. seems like an overkill to me.
4. just commit this file in my git repo. i really don't want to do that.
   I prefer option 2. I can live with option 3 if we can get a free tier. I really don't wanna go with 1 or 4. Open to suggestions!

Comment: 1 or 3 are your safest bets. And as it is a one-off, using scp to send up the file is quick and easy

Comment: how do you scp to heroku dyno? I can't find any resources on their official doc

Comment: need to go backwards and scp from inside the heroku instance to your local machine -- http://evans.io/legacy/posts/heroku-survival-guide/ for gudiance